# Is there a word to describe the set of permutations of each member of the powerset of a set?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

Just what it says on the tin:

For a set, X, is there a word to describe the union of sets of permutations of each member of the powerset of X?

Comment: @Zev thanks for the response, the second of your two suggestions is the right concept. I'll look up the 'partial permutation' phrase further.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer is satisfactory, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark just underneath the number and the up and down arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phrasing is a little unclear. If $X$ is our set and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is its power set, I think you either mean
$$\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal{P}(X))=\{\text{permutations of the set }\mathcal{P}(X)\}$$
or $$\bigcup_{S\in \mathcal{P}(X)}\operatorname{Aut}(S)=\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal{P}(X)}\{\text{permutations of the set }S\}$$
In the first case, I would just call it "permutations of the set of subsets of $X$", while in the second case, this set appears to be known as the set of [partial permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_permutation) of $X$.